# Как правильно верстать?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Цель вопроса: узнать, нет ли какого нибудь универсального способа верстки шаблонов.

Например, для красивого оформления форм, например `checkbox`: мы скрываем основной `checkbox` и рядом ставим метку `label` и оформляем с помощью `CSS` при нажатии на нее изменяем `checkbox` на `checked`.  Или можно обойтись без `label` – но с этим способом не знаком.

Про `select` написано куча статей, что до сих пор я мотаюсь от одного метода к другому и пробую все подряд выбирая что луче, но так и не выбрал.

Про кросcбраузерность: для оформления закругленных углов можно использовать `CSS 3`  что и удобно, но он не поддерживается некоторыми браузерами. Для всех браузеров нужно использовать `image`, что замедляет процесс верстки.

Мне хотелось бы узнать кто как верстает и почему…

Answer (score 6):

1. почему в тегах указан php?
2. интерес со стороны программиста или верстальщика?

Если ты программист, то начни с самых азов верстки. Универсального способа нет, хотя я не сталкивался с таким.
Вс страницы итак делаются по шаблонам, 1-2-3-4-5 колонок, потом только знай подписывай к ним свои стили и только.

Comment: 1. Хочу привлечь программистов так как они от части тоже верстальщики
2. интерес со стороны верстальщика

Comment: Ненавижу верстку, за последние 2 года с трудом садился за неё, да и уже многое в мире верстки изменилось что догонять нет особого желания.

Верстай так, как удобно тебе, верстай на хороший результат, прислушивайся к тем кому доверяешь, в общем тут говорить - то не особо нужно тут нужно практиковаться-практиковаться и еще много-много-много раз практиковаться.

Comment: Shrek, там не только php лишнее, но и python.
good, я вам советую почитать статьи и книги про верстку, а также часто заглядывать в исходный код понравившихся вам сайтов. Гарантирую, много нового для себя откроете.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [несколько статей по вёрстке сайтов](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout), посмотрите [некоторые способы реализаций различных макетов](http://htmlbook.ru/layout). Потом, когда набьёте руку, сможете создавать свои способы.

Answer (score 0):

В добавок к вышесказанному: возможно есть смысл посмотреть на [твиттеровский бутстрап](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). Не то чтобы я сильно любил эту штуку, но подчерпнуть что-то или использовать готовые кусочки можно.

Касательно чекбоксов, думаю, что любое решение будь то JQuery-плагин или изврат с перекрытием будут основанны на атрибуте checked. Если нет, поправьте. Буду рад :).
Разберитесь со способом который вам нравится больше всего и сохраните к себе в шаблон-заготовочку, чтобы по необходимости было ясно, какую картинку заменить.

Рекомендую копить такие готовые решения в заготовке, постепенно раздувая ее. Начать собирать такой шаблон можно с так называемого [бойлерплэйта](http://html5boilerplate.com/). Обратите так же внимание на препроцессор [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Во-первых удобно и круто :), во-вторых это позволит вам разбить CSS-код вашей заготовки на файлы и подключать по необходимости. По мимо основных файлов отвечающих за лэйаут и блоки, можно дробить до "переверстанные элементы форм", "футер прижатый к низу", к примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Старайся исключать картинки при верстке, читай статьи и думай как это можно написать кодом.  Css код сжимай, комментруйся, проверяй на валидацию ... 
Лично я смотрю код работ топовых веб студий, с опытом всё сам поймешь, как правильно и лучше;) Двигайся вперед, что раньше делали градиент картинкой, сейчас уже можно сделать кодом кроссбраузенро от ие5. И постоянно совершенствуйся!